# Django 404 Error, views not found. Why? View is not show up or is not found

Tags: python, django, linux, sqlite, model-view-controller

I programmed in Ruby beforehand and am now moving to Django. I am trying to follow the article here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

```
#polls/url.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

```
# mysite /urls.py
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

- > Here is my tree: polls/ -->
  > **init**.py ->
  > admin.py ->
  > apps.py ->
  > migrations/ -->
  > **init**.py ->
  > models.py ->
  > tests.py ->
  > urls.py ->
  > views.py ->

---

Of course, I ran `django-admin startproject mysite` before all of tihs and the output for the version is:

```
└──╼ $python -m django --version
4.0.4
```

I tried starting the server:

```
─╼ $python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 24, 2022 - 13:47:13
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

... but when I click the link I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    polls/
    admin/

The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Of which is a common 404 error. Why is this the case? I ran everything as instructed. Maybe there is something wrong with the sqlite server? I am very lost and any help will be appreciated,

Comment: You can only visit `polls/` and `admin/`, not `/`...

Comment: Sir Willem is right here, for `/...`  you need to give default route in `urls.py` which is already given and suggested by django in doc strings in urls.py , you've also uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any root route. So adding

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', **something**),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

should help or try to open http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Answer (score 0):

Your `polls/url.py` is based on the path 'polls/' (defined on `mysite/urls.py`)

Actually you only have two paths defined :

polls/

admin

If you add in `polls/url.py`

`path('index', views.index, name='index')`

You will also have the path `polls/index` defined